# blade component property undefined in server

Tags: php, laravel

i have table component like this

```php
// table.php

class table extends Component
{
    public  $pageName, $pagination, $tableData, $routeCreate, $filter, $showButton;
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($pageName, $pagination, $tableData, $routeCreate = null, $filter = null, $showButton = null)
    {
        $this->routeCreate = $routeCreate;
        $this->pageName = $pageName;
        $this->pagination = $pagination;
        $this->tableData = $tableData;
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->showButton = $showButton;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.table');
    }
}
```

and doing some null check

```php
// table.blade.php

@if ($filter)
   {{ $dropdown }}
@endif
```

it return undefined in server but return null in local

i try to debug the property using

```php
@php
    dd($filter);
@endphp
```

it return null in local and return error undefined in server, every variable i have null as default value, returning undefined in server

// **local**

[image]

// **Server**

[image]

Laravel version 9
php version PHP 8.1.2 in both server and local

Comment: Have you try : Ensure that the .env file configurations are consistent between local and server, especially the APP_ENV and APP_DEBUG settings.. Use php artisan view:clear php artisan optimize:clear and php artisan config:clear. Check if there are any server-specific configurations or security modules (like mod_security in Apache) that might be affecting the behavior of your application.

Comment: everything configured same, the app env are local and the app debug is true since i want to see the error, im not sure about server-specific configuration, im using nginx

Comment: its like, every variable i init null as default value, returning undefined in server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file and class names have to follow the [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) autoloading standards by being formatted in PascalCase.

Instead of:

```
class table extends Component
```

It should be:

```
class Table extends Component
```

Same story with your file name.

Comment: i dont understand why its not showing error in windows but showing error in linux, is there a diffrent version between php linux and php windows?